# Python - little LISP arithmetics interpreter

Tags: python, lisp, interpreter

I have input A and need to transform it into B using Python

A:

```
[['*', '1', '2', ['-', '4', '3']]]
```

B:

```
'1*2+(4-3)'
```

Will anybody please help ?

Comment: What you are looking for is a program to convert prefix to infix notation in Python. Also, your input data is wrong, it should be `[['+', '*', '1', '2', ['-', '4', '3']]]`

Comment: Why is this on hold as too broad? It says "I have input A and need to transform it into input B using Python". How could it be much narrower?

Comment: I'm no python programmer but the basic idea is to take the first element of the array between alle the rest elements of the array and recursively for array elements. I imagine you can do this with comprehensions. eg. `['+' '4' '5' [- '6' '3' '1']] => (4 + 5 + (6 - 3 - 1))`

Comment: @uliwitness I don't think it's too broad. But the OP needs to show a little effort (some code attempt) and not just "Can you please solve my problem for me?" Without any further information, it could be just a request to do someone's homework assignment for them.

Comment: Assuming this is meant to be Lispy, wouldn't the input need to be `['+',['*','1','2'],['-','4','3']] → (+ (* 1 2) (- 4 3)) → ( (1 * 2) + (4 - 3))` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this:

1) Tokenize the text. That is, go over the characters and build little objects that just contain the individual parts. In Python, you can use regexes for that part, in other programming languages one would just build a tiny state machine. So a list of tokens for your example in the end would be:

```
"[" "[" "*" "1" "2" "[" "-" "4" "3" "]" "]" "]"
```

2) Once you have a list of tokens, you can just chop the first element off the array and react to it. I.e. make a function that does the chopping and then calls another function to actually perform each element. In pseudocode:

```
fun parseOneElement tokens
    switch pop(tokens)
        case "[": return parseBrackets(tokens)
        case "*": return parseMultiplication(tokens)
        case "-": return parseSubtraction(tokens)
        else: return it
    end
end

fun parseBrackets tokens
    result := parseOneElement(tokens)
    pop(tokens,"]") or die
    return result
end

fun parseMultiplication tokens
    arg1 := parseOneElement(tokens)
    arg2 := parseOneElement(tokens)
    return "(" . arg1 . "*" . arg2 . ")"
end
```

etc. I.e. what you do is recursively unpack the expressions by grabbing the 2 arguments, again using parseOneElement.

Comment: Which programming language is this source code written in?

Comment: No particular language. Just an ad-hoc pseudocode I made up based on various other languages I've seen over the years.